# How to capitalize a variable in equation?

Tags: function-construction, replacement, parametric-functions

I have a function of following kind:
 
$f[\delta,\lambda]=A+B[\delta]+C[\lambda]+E[\delta,\lambda]$.
 Now, I want to make a function "g" from "f" such that
$g[f[\delta,\lambda]]=A+B[\delta]+C[\lambda]+E[\Delta,\Lambda]$
$g[f[\sigma,\omega]]=A+B[\sigma]+C[\omega]+E[\Sigma,\Omega]$ and so on for different pairs of variables like $(\alpha,\beta),(\delta,\lambda),(\mu,\nu)$ etc. in a single program. 
How to do this?

Comment: Posting Wolfram Language syntax is preferable to TeX.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use capital letters for variables. `D` is the mathematica command for derivative.

Second, use `ReplaceAll`

```
f[x_, y_] := a + b[x] + c[y] + d[x, y]
g[x_, y_] := f[x, y] /. d[x, y] -> d[x1, y1]
g[x, y]
```

> a + b[x] + c[y] + d[x1, y1]

or,

```
g[x_, y_] := f[x, y] /. d[x, y] -> d[X, Y]
g[x, y]
```

> a + b[x] + c[y] + d[X, Y]

Comment: But this will work for (x,y) only. If I want to run it for (x,y),(p,q),(r,s) etc. many pairs, it will not work.

Comment: in that case you have replace them all like `g[x_, y_] := f[x, y] /. {d[x, y] -> d[X, Y], a[x]->a[q]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Attributes[tuc] = {Listable};

tuc[x_] := x // ToString // ToUpperCase // ToExpression

f[x_, y_] := a + b[x] + c[y] + e[x, y]

g[x_, y_] := f[x, y] /. e[x, y] :> e @@ tuc[{x, y}]

g[σ, ω]

(*  a + b[σ] + c[ω] + e[Σ, Ω]  *)
```